# Use Spacy to find Lemma of Russian (Those langs which don't have model)

Tags: nlp, spacy

I have downloaded Spacy English model and finding lemma using this code.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u'Two apples')
for token in doc:
    print(token, token.lemma, token.lemma_)
```

**Output:**

```
Two 11711838292424000352 two
apples 8566208034543834098 apple
```

Now I wanted to do same thing for **Russian** language. But Spacy don't have models for Russian language. But I am seeing their [GitHub code for Russian language](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/spacy/lang/ru) and I think that code could be used to find lemma.

I am new to Spacy. Will needed a starting point for those languages which don't have models. Also I have noted that for some languages let say for URDU they have provided a [look up dictionary](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/ur/lemmatizer.py) for lemmatization.

I want to expand this thing to all those languages which don't have models.

Note: In above code I believe that it could be further improved as in my case I needed lemma only so what are the things which I can turn off and how?

Comment: Use can use multi-language Spacy package and see the accuracy

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I have checked that is not helpful.

Comment: Does converting Russian to English using Google Translate and then find lemma and convert back to English..Makes sense ?

Comment: Not a feasible solution in my case.

Comment: Hmm
They have given code on GitHub, I am struggling on how I can use it. If you see above GitHub code and can share some simple code example that will be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

- This won't be optimal in spacy if a model is not present.
- StanfordNLP has more language coverage, and has Russian language models : https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/installation_download.html

[image]
- spaCy recently launched a handy wrapper over Stanford NLP, so you can use StanfordNLP goodies seamlessly within spaCy pipelines:

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-stanfordnlp

The code would look something like this ( not tested ) :

```
import stanfordnlp
from spacy_stanfordnlp import StanfordNLPLanguage

stanfordnlp.download("ru")

snlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(lang="ru")
nlp = StanfordNLPLanguage(snlp)

doc = nlp("Привет мир, это Россия")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.dep_)
```

Comment: Stanford CoreNLP supports lemma for English language only. Check this link: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html

Comment: The benchmarking results indicate that the Russian language models do support lemma -> https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/performance.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I also found out this link later on.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Spacy with russian model `ru2` from [this project](https://github.com/buriy/spacy-ru). It works.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use Stanza (previously StandfordNLP) for this

```py
import stanza
from spacy_stanza import StanzaLanguage

stanza.download('ru')  # will take a while

snlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang="ru")
nlp = StanzaLanguage(snlp)

text = "Андре́й Серге́евич Арша́вин (род. 29 мая 1981[4], Ленинград) — российский футболист, бывший капитан сборной России, заслуженный мастер спорта России (2008)."
doc = nlp(text)

for token in doc:
    print(token, token.lemma, token.lemma_)
```

All available models are listed here https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/models.html

Comment: I get `ImportError: The Russian lemmatizer requires the pymorphy2 library` . Is stanza just a wrapper for the pymorphy2 library?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Russian lemmatizer](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/ru/lemmatizer.py) from spaCy. Following this [tutorial](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#language-data) the result will be:

```
from spacy.lang.ru import Russian
nlp = Russian()

def lemmatization(text):
   doc = nlp(text)
   for token in doc:
      print(token, token.lemma, token.lemma_)
   tokens = [token.lemma_ for token in doc]
   return " ".join(tokens)

text = "Андре́й Серге́евич Арша́вин (род. 29 мая 1981[4], Ленинград) — российский футболист, бывший капитан сборной России, заслуженный мастер спорта России (2008)."
lemmatization(text)
```

**Output**:

```
'Андре́й серге́ Арша́вин ( род . 29 мая 1981[4 ] , Ленинград ) — российский футболист , бывший капитан сборной России , заслуженный мастер спорт России ( 2008 ) .'
```

It also can be useful to use stemming after lemmatization:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language='russian')
tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer()

def stemming(text):
   tokens = [stemmer.stem(w) for w in tokenizer.tokenize(text)]
   return " ".join(tokens)

stemming(text)
```

**Output:**

```
'андре́ серге́евич арша́вин (род. 29 ма 1981[4], ленинград) — российск футболист, бывш капита сборн россии, заслужен мастер спорт росс (2008).'
```

Comment: The stemming below worked, but the lemmatization above does not return the same text as shown in the output for me.